# What it the relationship between Type theory and logic?

Tags: logic, types, symbolic-logic

I am aware that a similar question was asked about the type theory in the principia, but I'm more interested in what the relationship between, say Martin-Lof Type theory and intuitionistic logic is.

Comment: What have you uncovered in your research so far? The ["Propositions as Types" paper (pdf)](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/propositions-as-types/propositions-as-types.pdf) may be a good place to start gathering context

Answer (score 3):

For [Type theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/) you can see :

- Peter Andrews, [An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory : To Truth Through Proof](https://books.google.it/books?id=UaPuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) (1986)
- J.Roger Hindley, [Basic Simple Type Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=XgyI7vY0BLgC&printsec=frontcover) (1997)
- Fairouz Kamareddine & Twan Laan, [A Modern Perspective on Type Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZIHs6Kar0vIC&pg=PR1) (2004)

as well as :

- William Farmer, [The Seven Virtues of Simple Type Theory](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S157086830700081X/1-s2.0-S157086830700081X-main.pdf?_tid=56777100-642f-11e5-99e4-00000aacb360&acdnat=1443259198_e4658abd2e62333d93cc776ef21d331d) (2008).

---

On *Intuitionistic TT* :

- Per Martin-Löf, [Intuitionistic type theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=_D0ZAQAAIAAJ) (1984)
- Johan Georg Granström, [Treatise on Intuitionistic Type Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=-u4IVP-3qh4C&printsec=frontcover) (2011).